# Anyway to configure authorization logout url in Oauth2 client api Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I have a logout url, to logout from the Authorization server.
Logout Url: https://.../nidp/app/logout

note: this url displays the response in jsp file

How can I configure this url in the Spring Boot Oauth2 Client application?

Currently, I have configured as below

@GetMapping(value = "/api/v1/logout", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

```
private String checkOut()
{
    RestTemplate restTemp = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("", headers);
    final String uri = "https://.../nidp/app/logout";     
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemp.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class); 
    return "Logged out";
}
```